# Difference in use between 正義 and しか勝たん

Tags: word-choice, slang

I find them used interchangeably. Do they have a different nuance?

Comment: Probably you better add examples you've seen to get an answer. They should be internet slangs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-しか勝たん is a fandom slang that means something (or rather, usually a person) is "the best."

https://www.nli-research.co.jp/report/detail/id=64923?pno=2&site=nli

> 自分の推しが一番いい、一番かわいい、といったように推しを称賛する際に「推ししか勝たん」と言い始めたのが起源だとされている。

-は正義 can be used similarly, too. [A fandom website](https://www.paradisearmy.com/doujin/pasok_katan.htm) says they mean more or less the same, and appeared more or less in the same period.

Answer (score 0):

は正義 feels like "this is so good".
This feels like there can be another choice that is as good as it but you rate it so high at least.
正義 is so similar to 最高(not literally the best).
風呂上がりのビールは正義(you may enjoy other things as this)
クイズノックは正義(there can be as good a youtuber as them)
カイリューのしんそくは正義(there can be as strong a move as it)

しか勝たん has a nuance of comparing it to other things.
It feels like "I love this, there's no other choice."
風呂上がりのビールしか勝たん
YouTuberはクイズノックしか勝たん

However you can use this if it's not the best, when you pretend that you love it too much so that you're being blind.
カイリューのしんそくしか勝たん